# Imitate incoming call behavior on android

Tags: android, node.js, real-time

I'm working on a project to send free calls over wi-fi. I'm using Node.js on the back end with sockets to send the voice. And I want to "notify" the user on **real time** when he has an incoming call from my service. It is very important to be on real time. Otherwise the user won't know when he is receiving a call.

I want to imitate the same behavior an incoming call has on android. That means I want to wake the device and send it to my android activity every time it receives a call.

I don't know how to implement this feature. Should I create a service that uses a socket to listen my server always?, Or should I create a "alarm" to check every 5 seconds or so?. Or a totally different solution?

I don't want to consume too many resources from the device. Hope I was clear enough. Please ask If you need any clarification of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Messaging to wake up your connection with the server. A service always can be closed by the SO. An Activiy and activity connection always can be closed by the SO and an alarm can consume a lot of memory.